# NXP Explore NFC using libnfc on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, nfc

I am thinking of starting a project where I use the NXP Explore-NFC board for the Raspberry Pi so that I can write NDEF messages to the NFC via an Android device. I currently own the Raspberry Pi and the NXP Explore-NFC board. I have been doing some research and know that you can use the libnfc library with the board. My background is in Java and Android development, so I have very little experience in embedded systems. This is why I wanted to use the libnfc library.

I wanted to know if anyone has managed to get this working with the same NFC board and if so, do I need to learn any new programming languages to achieve this. If anyone has any information about this please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might try http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I have now posted the question on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Here is the link:
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17057/nxp-explore-nfc-using-libnfc-on-raspberry-pi